# validation on button without refresh page on APEX5 5.0

Tags: oracle-apex

Need your suggestions on handling the validation without submitting page in APEX 5.0. I have following items on my apex report page.

- "Select list" item which contains some static values
- date pickers ( start date and end date)
- Submit button ( Once submit is clicked the report date is displayed )

Here I need to add a dynamic action or validation to the submit button so that if user clicks the submit button without selecting a value from the "Select List", an error message should be displayed to the user that he needs to select the item first from the "Select list" page item. With out any selection from the list , the processing should stop and a warning message should be displayed ( either it could be popup message or message can be marked on the select list page item ) .Point to be noted here that during the submit I do not want to refresh  the page, just would like a quick error message to display.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a similar case i used dynamic actions
dynamic actions works on client side

in my case i am not enabling submit button until user changes the select list value

in my dynamic action my config is as below

- Event=change
- selection=items
- item=selectlistID

and true action is

- action=disable
- button=submitbuttonname

in your case you can choose javascript as action and add your javascript code